# Cannot return paginated result from service in angular 5

Tags: angular5

I have the following code which returned paginated result from my service. I just switched to angular 5 and now the code doesn't work anymore

```
return this._http.get(
        this.userManagerResourceApiUrl + "GetAllUsers/" + tierID + "/" + countryID + "/" + officeID + "/" + filter
    ).map((res: Response) => {
            paginatedResult.result = res.json();

            if (res.headers.get("Pagination") != null) {
                var paginationHeader: Pagination = this.itemsService.getSerialized<Pagination>(JSON.parse(res.headers.get("Pagination")));
                paginatedResult.pagination = paginationHeader;
            }

            this.totalItems = paginatedResult.pagination.TotalItems;
            return paginatedResult;
        }).catch(this.handleError);
```

I get the following error message

```
Type 'Promise<any>' is not assignable to type 'IUser[]'
```

Comment: In which line, you are getting this error?

Comment: on this line "paginatedResult.result = res.json();"

Answer (score 1):

In angular 5,  You don't need to map to json anymore and remove any `map(res => res.json())` calls, which are no longer needed.

Things to take care while upgrading your project to angular 5.
[https://onlyforcoder.blogspot.in/2017/11/angular-5-upgrade-your-project-To-Angular5.html](https://onlyforcoder.blogspot.com/2017/11/angular-5-upgrade-your-project-To-Angular5.html)